# Is it safe for me to upgrade to me to upgrade from Ubuntu Kinetic to Lunar (ZFS boot)

Tags: boot, upgrade, zfs

I installed Ubuntu 22.10/Kinetic with the ZFS filesystem option.  I would like to upgrade to 23.04/Lunar but am concerned about whether the system will be bootable after upgrade due to lagging ZFS kernel support.

My understanding is that Lunar jumps to Kernel 6.2 but ZFS just added Kernel 6.2 support.  It doesn't look like Ubuntu ZFS was updated in time to be included in the release.

Will the upgraded system be bootable?

This happened with an earlier upgrade.  I had to install a PPA (here [https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/zfs](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/zfs)) to get support.

Unfortunately it doesn't look like Jonathon F is supporting his PPA any more.

Is it safe to upgrade?

Comment: It is always **risky** to upgrade to a new version of an operating system. It will normally work, but it is important to **backup** everything that you cannot afford to lose before you start upgrading.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  The reason I chose zfs is for sending snapshots for backup.  So got that covered.  Can anyone respond with something helpful?  Sad the relevant & timely question got negged and ignored.  Is it a dumb question?

Comment: If the system breaks, the snapshots might no longer work. So you should have some other backup, that can stand by itself.

Comment: There seems to be some relevant info here https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/software/distributions/1383195-ubuntu-23-04-desktop-s-new-installer-set-to-ship-without-openzfs-install-support/page5

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [take the tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) to learn how Ask Ubuntu works. Read [how to ask](https://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question. Learn what an [on-topic question](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) is. Then take a look to [the help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) to see if some _on-topic questions_ are already asked.

Comment: Reviewed referenced documents.  Can you point out what is wrong with this question?  Seems relevant, timely and on-topic that could help prevent others from disasters I've previously experienced.  Responses seem way off and entirely unhelpful from my perspective.